# Why can't my Django application reach my Postgres server?

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, database-connection

Both servers are VirtualBox servers on my host machine, and I'm able to network between them just fine (ssh from one to the other, etc.), other than this issue (which I don't know enough about to rule out networking as a potential cause).

Pertaining to the database server:

1. My IP tables allow for all TCP access on port `5432`
2. I've created a Postgres database which can be opened and queried using the `psql` shell without issue, using the `foo1` user
3. I've installed psychopg2
4. My Django application is configured with the default database (the only one configured, in fact) to use the IP of my server at port `5432`, using the `foo1` user, and the password set to `foo1`'s password
5. I'm using Postgres 9.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 with the latest psychopg2 and Django 1.5 beta

The error is coming from psychopg2's initial connection attempt and has no error message (otherwise, I might not have to ask this). It is simply, `OperationalError`. So, my question, more specifically, is: What are some of the more obvious things that I left out of that list, which could be causing this issue.

Traceback - from uWSGI log, so no context :(

```
# ... 10 + frames above here ommitted, since the they amount to
# essentially MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)

File "/var/www/myapp/deps/current/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 316, in cursor
    cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)

File "/var/www/myapp/deps/current/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 210, in _cursor
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)

File "/var/www/myapp/deps/current/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 183, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)

File "/var/www/myapp/deps/current/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 178, in connect
    return _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)

OperationalError
```

Comment: Can you `psql` from the django-running VM to the database on the Postgres-running VM?

Comment: @MattBall - I wasn't aware one could even do such a thing. I don't have Postgres installed on the app server - Can I install *just* the `psql` shell, and if so, how do i connect to a server on another virtual machine like that? (thanks in advance)

Comment: This really belongs as an entirely separate Q&A, probably on a different SE site, but I'll bite. I don't recall if you can install just the shell. I _think_ you can, but even if not it shouldn't really matter. Use a package manager to install it. RTFD, but tl;dr use the `-h` option (as in, `psql -h somehost`) to specify the host on which the db server is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a PostgreSQL client only, and that will give you psql.

For Windows, install the ODBC driver and you'll get psql. Get it here:
[PostgreSQL ODBC Driver](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/)

On Linux, your package manager should have a postgresql-client-XXX package. In Ubuntu it's called postgresql-client-9.1 for example.

Comment: thanks. It was listen_adresses setting in PG. That helped me discover it.